# How do I write directly into the console?

Tags: firefox, browser, console, firebug, inspector

I read an answer to a question on SO and someone suggested writing directly into the console. I thought, that sounds cool let's give it a go. I proceeded to make an attempt, but I couldn't figure it out. How do I write/run code directly in the console? I tried in Firebug & Firefox's inspector and I did a little Google search as well. Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug has two ways to execute some code (and write to the console). These are the [Command Line](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line) at the bottom of the [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel):

[image: Firebug Command Line]

and the [Command Editor](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Editor) if you want to write some larger scripts:

[image: Firebug Command Editor]

which is available by clicking the little arrow at the right side of the Console panel:

[image: Command Editor toggle button]

The Firefox DevTools have a similar feature to the Command Editor of Firebug called [Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools/Scratchpad):

[image]

This tool is available via the Firefox menu > *Developer* > *Scratchpad* or by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

MDN has some example about [Outputting text to the console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console).

The most simple example is:
`console.log("Hello World!");` Which should show up in the Firefox Console. (There might be some issue if you use Firebug at the same time)

Comment: I understand how to output text to the console. I'm wondering how I can enter text in the console - live - while viewing a webpage. Perhaps I misunderstood and this is not possible...